# Bootstrap lock icon not displaying

Tags: html

I am trying to add the lock icon on my website using the following code,

```
<div style="width:10%; background-color:#D6B300; height:50px;">
    <p style="color:#044B29;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Lock</p>
</div>
```

But for some reason it is not displaying on the [site](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/). Please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site includes Font Awesome CSS but you were using Gylphicon classes in your span.

**Right code:**

```
<span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
```